# Unable to Perform Oracle Golden Gate remote oui installation Solaris 11

Tags: oracle, unix, operating-system, solaris

I tried to install Oracle Golden Gate 12c on Solaris SPARC 11.2. I set up environment variable as

```
bash$ export DISPLAY=ip_address:0.0
```

but i get error as follows

```
Checking monitor: must be configured to display at least 256 colors
>>> Could not execute auto check for display colors using command /usr/openwin/bin/xdpyinfo. Check if the DISPLAY variable is set.    Failed <<<<
```

I maybe mistaken in setting display environment on Solaris 11.2 as I'm only accustomed to Solaris 10. I don't expect much difference between Solaris 10 and 11 but then again, I maybe mistaken.

Do help, thanks.

Comment: What says `/usr/openwin/bin/xdpyinfo`?

Comment: It says check if DISPLAY variable is set. which i had, and already launch xming also.

Comment: `ping ip_address` and `telnet ip_address 6000`?

Comment: `xming` is your X server.  Simply starting that does not mean something on another host is going to be able to connect.

Comment: Does running `xterm` on the Solaris system work?